# Encrypt Jar file, alterate data, encrypt it again and save

Tags: php, encryption, jar, aes

I need to make a php script to do the following sequence:

- 1) User enters a secret key, let's call it $user_key
- 2) Read the default file content (file_get_contents is saved in $data)
- 3) Encrypt the $data in AES 128 with 3 random keys (saved in $data)
- 4) Concatenate those 3 keys at the end of $data
- 5) Pad the data
- 6) Encrypt the $data with the user's secret key
- 7) Write the $data to an unique file

It works (Java decryption) if I only do the parts 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 and 7. It doesn't work at all (Java decryption doesn't work) if I encrypt the file with the random keys.

Did I make something wrong in Php (Like a missing padding or something)?

Here is the code I use. I've marked line 1 to 3 those which make the script not to work well.

```
$data = file_get_contents('default_file.jar');

// Generate 3 AES keys
$ramdom_key_1 = randomAESKey();
$ramdom_key_2 = randomAESKey();
$ramdom_key_3 = randomAESKey();

// Encrypt three times the raw data with the user key
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $ramdom_key_1);      // LINE 1
$data = AESEncrypt($data, $ramdom_key_2);               // LINE 2
$data = AESEncrypt($data, $ramdom_key_3);               // LINE 3

// Add the 3 keys to the data raw
$data .= $ramdom_key_3 . $ramdom_key_2 . $ramdom_key_1;

// Final encryption with the user's key
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $user_key);

// Write the raw data to an unique file
file_put_contents('new_file.jar', $data);
```

Here is my Java code to decrypt the file:

```
byte[] content = download(url);
content = Crypto.decrypt(content, user_key);

String content = new String(data);
String keys = content.substring(content.length() - 48, content.length());
String[] keys = new String[] { keys.substring(0, 16), keys.substring(16, 32), keys.substring(32, 48) };

byte[] cleared_content = new byte[content.length - 48];
System.arraycopy(content, 0, cleared_content, 0, content.length - 48);

// For each keys, decrypt the file data
for (String key : keys)
{
    cleared_content = Crypto.decrypt(cleared_content, key.getBytes());
}

return cleared_content;
```

My crypto class looks like this (Just a small part of it):

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] input)
{
    try
    {
        SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return input;
}
```

As the keys are stored in a desc order, I just have to execute the decryption like that.

Quick edit to show my pad function in php:

```
function pad($data, $blocksize)
{ 
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize); 
    return $data . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
}
```

Comment: First of all, please update the question with the actual error description. "It does not work at all" is not a good error description. Add the Java decryption code if at all possible.

Comment: There is not something inherently wrong with the code from a programming standpoint. I wonder if you decrypt in Java using the right mode and padding though, and using the keys in the correct order. If you only apply padding for encryption pass #1, you should not expect padding for decryption pass #1 and #2 in Java. I won't go into the futility of encrypting something and appending the keys to the ciphertext.

Comment: A user cannot enter a key, a user can only enter a pass phrase. Keys are not pass phrases. You need a key derivation function to securily convert a pass phrase to a key, such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt. And if you are going that way, you might just use password based encryption as defined in PKCS#5 public standard by RSA labs.

Comment: @owlstead I've added the java code. I don't have any error, that's just when I save the byte array into a file (on my disk) it doesn't work (Invalid file). When I do the same thing without first encryptions (php) and then decryption (Java) it saves the data into a valid file that I can execute. About your 3rd comment, this is just a typo. The content is encrypted in ECB.

Comment: Oh boy, where do I start. Keys consist of bits, normally octets, not Strings. You don't seem to have any specific switches on the padding. What is this `Crypto` class?

Comment: I've edited my first post with the Crypto class.

Comment: Your Crypto class seems to always expect padding (PKCS#5 should always contain at least one padding byte) and your PHP code does not always pad.

Comment: So, if I understand what you are saying, I have to use this code everytime, right? `AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $password)`

Comment: Yes, presuming `pad()` does perform PKCS#5 padding (or PKCS#7 padding for AES, officially, but that's the same).

Comment: I've edited my first post with the padding function I'm using. I'll try to pad my stuff when I'll be back home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks to [owlstead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/owlstead).

I changed

```
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $ramdom_key_1);      // LINE 1
$data = AESEncrypt($data, $ramdom_key_2);               // LINE 2
$data = AESEncrypt($data, $ramdom_key_3);               // LINE 3
```

to

```
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $ramdom_key_1);      // LINE 1
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $ramdom_key_2);      // LINE 2
$data = AESEncrypt(pad($data, 16), $ramdom_key_3);      // LINE 3
```